# Error infinite loop in java program

Tags: java

I tried to run a program that returns a Diamond ring(String).
No errors in compilation but when i run it , the execution didn't stop.

```
class Diamond {
  public static String print(int n) {
      int j=n/2,i=0,k=1;
      String ch="";
      while(i<n){
         for(int c=0;c<java.lang.Math.abs(j);c--)
             ch=ch + " ";
         for(int r=0;r<k;r++)
             ch=ch + "*";
          j--;
          if(j<=-1){
              k=k-2;
           }
          else{
              k=k+2;
          }
          j--;
          ch=ch + "\n";
          i++;
}
    return ch ;              
}
    public static void main(String []args){
      System.out.println(Diamond.print(5));
    }
}
```

This my code, i think that an infinite loop, but i can't spot it.

Comment: `c=0;c<java.lang.Math.abs(j);c--`, `c` probably starts smaller and will only get smaller, so this might be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your first `for` loop change `c--` for `c++` like:

```
for(int c=0;c<java.lang.Math.abs(j);c++)
```

As you are comparing `c` with a higher value, if you decrement `c` you'll never reach this value (`abs(j)`), actually you are distancing from it. Thus getting the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
int c=0;c<java.lang.Math.abs(j);c--
```

You are decrementing c and comparing it to a positive value so it will never get java.lang.Math.abs(j) unless j was 0

Try this:

```
int c=0;c<java.lang.Math.abs(j);c++
```